# Setting up IJulia

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I am trying to set up IJulia on my PC, but after I get it running I get the constant messages that "kernel has died" and there is a problem with ZMQ library.

Trying to rebuild or reinstall ZMQ does not work. I get an error:

```
================================[ BUILD ERRORS ]================================

WARNING: ZMQ had build errors.

 - packages with build errors remain installed in C:\Users\Gisaev\.julia\v0.3
 - build the package(s) and all dependencies with `Pkg.build("ZMQ")`
 - build a single package by running its `deps/build.jl` script
```

Trying to execute build.jl by line (part that correspond to windows) I get the error "Provider PackageManager faild to satisfy dependency zmq."

I am kind of lost here, because ZMQ is obviously correctly installed and working for [IPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython) - IPython notebooks work just fine; I have a fresh installation from [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)).

Comment: What version of Julia are you using?

Comment: I use Juno bundle,  64 bit, i believe it is v0.3.9. Ipython is from Anaconda 3.4 64 bit installation.

Comment: Can you try starting Julia again and trying to build it again? Can you also post the full log from Pkg.add? The error may have occurred before that point.

Comment: =================================[ ERROR: ZMQ ]=================================

Provider PackageManager failed to satisfy dependency zmq
while loading C:\Users\-----\.julia\v0.3\ZMQ\deps\build.jl, in expression starting on line 23

Comment: It seems that there is unfixed bug somewhere in Juno distribution. Latest 64 bit Juno is version 0.3.7 and it has this bug. If i install latest Julia 0.4.0 - zero MQ builds correctly and everything is fine with Ijulia notebooks using 0.4.0 version.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you solved it?

Comment: I kind of ditched Juno - it is to buggy. Here is a nice tutorial on setting up Julia from scratch.http://quant-econ.net/jl/getting_started.html better go with ijulia and notebooks i guess. generally dissapointed with julia bugginess, compared to R it is a total mess...

Answer (score 1):

Try to run

```
Pkg.build("ZMQ")
```

to see what happens.

If there are warnings about "libpgm" and "zeromq32", you can delete the *lib* directories and then try to build ZMQ again.

```
rm -rf /Users/username/.julia/v0.x/Homebrew/deps/usr/Cellar/zeromq32/3.2.5
rm -rf /Users/username/.julia/v0.x/Homebrew/deps/usr/Cellar/libpgm/5.2.122
Pkg.build("ZMQ")
```

This will correctly build the libpgm and zeromq32 you needed.

(I suppose the operation system is OS X. If you are using Windows, please refer to *[Installing ZMQ on Windows 7+ seems to require admin privileges #69](https://github.com/JuliaInterop/ZMQ.jl/issues/69)*.)